# Add Member to Marketing List in Power Automate with Microsoft Dataverse

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate

How do I add an existing contact as an Member into a Marketing List via Power Automate with Microsoft Dataverse?

[image]

I've found this article: https://functionalthoughts.com/how-to-add-to-a-member-to-a-microsoft-dynamics-365-marketing-list-using-power-automate/

But he used CDS while I'm working with Microsoft Dataverse. Sadly I haven't found an Microsoft Dataverse Action for adding a Contact to a Marketing List. I assumed that I could use 'Update a Row' but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Receive the needed Marketing List with 'List Rows'.

Use 'Perform a bound action' Action. You need the 'listid' + 'contactid'

[image]